# With PHP, how do I get the corresponding column in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a "contacts" table like this :

```
contact_auto_inc     user_id     contact_id     
      1              1             3
      2              1             5
      3              2             1
      4              3             5
      5              3             2
      6              1             6
```

and a "user" table like this :

```
 user_id        username
     1          Simon
     2            Bill
     3            Tim
     4          Brendan
     5            Chris
     6            Noel
```

What I want is to print the matching `usernames` of the `contact_ids`.

So for `user_id` 1, for example, I want to print :

```
Tim
Chris
Noel
```

How I can I do this ?

I can print the `contact_ids` from the `contacts` table alright with :

```
     $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

//we want to show contact_ids in the contacts table that have the $user_id above. 
     $select_from_contacts_table = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

//get the result of the above
     $result=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_contacts_table);

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $contact_id=$row['contact_id'];
     echo $contact_id  . "<br>";
 }
```

This would print :

```
3
5
6
```

But how I can I print the corresponding `username` column in the `user` table? I have been trying for hours with an `INNER JOIN` but keep getting errors and wrong results, something along the lines of :

```
 $select_from_user_table = "SELECT DISTINCT contact_id, username
FROM contacts 
INNER JOIN user
ON contacts.contact_id=user.user_id WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";

//get the result of the above
$result2=mysqli_query($con,$select_from_user_table); 

//show the usernames
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
echo $row['username']  . "<br>";
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just wrote the  correct SQL with INNER JOIN and was posting for you but I noticed that it is exactly the same with yours except DISTINCT - which wouldn't be any difference. Weird it fails.

Comment: Ahh! user_id = part at the end. It is supposed to be contacts.user_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT contacts.contact_id, user.username
FROM contacts
    INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = contacts.contact_id
WHERE contacts.user_id = 1
```

With '$user_id' instead of 1 in the php code of course.

EDIT: Ok, I didn't put DISTINCT considering you also return contact_id in your query. However, if you don't need contact id related results but distinct users then add DISTINCT but remove contact_id like below.

Still solution is about using user_id with table name since it is existing in both table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.username
FROM contacts
    INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = contacts.contact_id
WHERE contacts.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help, works perfect now even without DISTINCT. And it makes sense to me now too, of course having to put the table name first like contacts.contact_id. Thanks to all the answers below also.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can query for username in while loop like below :

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $contact_id=$row['contact_id'];

     $query = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id = '".$contact_id."' ";
     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
     echo $row['username'];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  need to join the `Contact` Table twice back to the User table using different Aliases for each join on `contact_id` and  `user_id` columns. something like....

```
SELECT C.contact_id, U1.username
FROM `contacts` C
INNER JOIN `user` U  ON C.user_id = U.user_id 
INNER JOIN `user` U1 ON C.contact_id = U1.user_id 
WHERE C.user_id = '$user_id'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. You need to perform a double `JOIN` like

```
SELECT DISTINCT contact_id, username
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN user u ON c.user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN user u1 ON u1.user_id = c.contact_id
WHERE c.user_id = '$user_id'
```